file upload via camel-netty
I have the following router to receive incoming tcp packets:
    <camelContext id="netty-test" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">

    <route id="netty-test">
        <from uri="netty4:tcp://0.0.0.0:8089?sync=false"/>
        <to uri="file:data/files"/>
    </route>

</camelContext>

and the client code to send the file
public class Client {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    File file = new File("test_file.xml"); 

    try (Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8089)) {


        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;

        while ((bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }


        fileInputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

if the file is small - I see one message in my data/files folder, but when the file is larger than 10kb I see N number of parts.
How should I solve this problem: use camel aggregator (but I don't know neither the number of parts nor any sign of end of download), or should I make a custom decoder for camel-netty component (I saw examples in https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction2/tree/master/chapter6/netty but I didn't find an example where two tcp packets are converted into one message)?

